If $V_n$ is a cozero set, then $V_n \cap H = f^{-1}(U_n)$
I'm trying to understand Katchenko's proof about the equivalence between $z$-embedded subgroups and $\mathbb{R}$-factorizable topological groups. Just to know: A subgroup $H$ of a $\mathbb{R}-$factorizable topological group is $\mathbb{R}-$factorizable iff $H$ is $z$-embedded in $G$.
To remember: Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subseteq X$ a subspace. $A$ is $z$-embedded in $X$ if all cozero set $B$ in $A$ has the form $B = A \cap C $, where $C$ is a cozero set in $X$.
In my context, I have a subgroup $H$ of a Tychonoff topological group $G$, where $H$ is $z$-embedded in $G$. The proof of $(\Longleftarrow)$ goes like this:
We consider the family $\gamma = \{U_n : n \in \omega\}$ of open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ with rationals end points, and a continuous function $f: H \to \mathbb{R}$. For each $n \in \omega$, one can choose $V_n \subset G$ a cozero set such that $V_n \cap H = f^{-1}(U_n)$.
I don't understand why it's guaranteed that $f^{-1}(U_n)$ can be written in that form. My attempt was to show that the set of cozeros form a base of open sets for $G$, and union of cozeros is cozero, so any open set in $H$ can be written as a union of cozero sets intersected with space $H$, then I would have the desired form for $f^{-1}(U_n)$ but it seems to fail when we have more than $\omega$ cozero sets.  Maybe I'm missing something a little bit obvious
